# How to set persistent notification background image

Tags: android, notifications, android-notification-bar

I have been developing an android application in which I need to set a persistent notification, which never goes away from the status bar. All things are setup properly, but I need to use full background in the notification without any text or anything. As I have attached a screenshot.

[image: Notification Background like Yandex Search app]

I have used the following code:

```
String notificationTitle = "Here My App Name Goes";
        String notificationMessage = "Search with ---------";

        Intent targetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        targetIntent.setClassName(this, this.getClass().getName());

        int requestCode = AppSingleton.NOTIFICATION_ID_ALWAYS;

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                requestCode, targetIntent, 0);
        String statusBarTickerText = "Search from ----------";
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon,
                statusBarTickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT
                | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, notificationTitle,
                notificationMessage, contentIntent);

        nm.notify(AppSingleton.NOTIFICATION_ID_ALWAYS, notification);
```

I can set my app icon and write some text over it, but I need to set full background as it is the screenshot provided.

Please help me getting out of this prm.

Comment: @Marc: Any idea about my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I got no idea. I have never coded for android. Hopefully, someone will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the remedy for my problem, just have to make custom notification layout with some code change. Below is my edited code.:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, "All ----",
                System.currentTimeMillis());

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.notification);

        notification.contentView = contentView;
        final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,
                MainActivity.class);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

        nm.notify(AppSingleton.NOTIFICATION_ID_ALWAYS, notification);
```

As you can see above RemoteViews class did my work without a problem. Just made a layout and referenced it here. And, boom got the background for my notification.